# How peers belong to Organizations endorse hyperledgerl fabric update transaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I am new to blockchain  technology  let alone hyperledger fabric.
But as far as I understand all the nodes or peers of other organizations  are involved while application / user requests  for update transaction. And if all the nodes of network agrees  to the proposal, leger  gets updated.

[I am following  this link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/write_first_app.html)

And I coudnt find when the nodes of organisations agreed to update transactions?

Am I getting  it all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you read the Fabric Key Concepts topics, you could start with the [Peers topic](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/peers/peers.html).

In a nutshell, you can define the endorsement policy for any smart contract which defines which organization's peers must execute the transaction and agree on the results before it gets validated and committed to a blockchain channel.

Answer (score 1):

If you usually see the organization's and it's corresponding peer's will be **joining a channel** and do all the transactions (any operation like create,query etc ..). There is a ledger for a channel and all peer's have a copy of that ledger.

For your question

> And I coudnt find when the nodes of organisations agreed to update transactions?

Let's take **A** as an **peer** from **organization** **Org1**  tries to update the value in the ledger. ( So this can be basically called as any client(application) tries to send an request to update something in ledger)

Now this request, someone has to validate. That's where **endorsing peer** (these are the peer's where chaincode (buisness logic)  is installed) comes into picture. Now this transaction done by A will be validated by the policies that are defined in chaincode.

You can refer about endorsing peers and policies [here](https://medium.com/kokster/hyperledger-fabric-endorsing-transactions-3c1b7251a709)